# Access erasing SQL contents of query after first run

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am using Microsoft Access 2010 and had a corrupted database.  The database is split with the back end on a server.  I imported all the front end objects (relationships, etc.) into a new front end and relinked all the tables.  Most everything is fine and this is how I have done it previously.  However, I have one query that is causing me problems.

I can only run the query once.  After the query is run, the SQL statement gets automatically deleted from that query.  I have worked with compact and repair and all sorts of other save options but I can only get the SQL statement to stick once.  I can open and close the database multiple times, I can open and close the query in SQL view multiple times, but once I run the query, the SQL statement disappears.

This query worked fine prior to the corruption and actually works fine now, other than I can only run the query once.

I don't think it makes a difference but my SQL statement is below:

```
SELECT qryAutonumber2.Date_1 AS Date_Time, 
        qryAutonumber2.DTW, 
        qryAutonumber2.Temp_C, 
        qryAutonumber2.WL_Elev_Difference AS Daily_WL_Elev_Difference, 
        qryAutonumber2.PT_ID_1 AS PT_ID, 
        qryAutonumber2.Remarks
FROM    tblFlag, 
        (qryAutonumber2 
        INNER JOIN tblTransducer 
            ON qryAutonumber2.PT_ID_1 = tblTransducer.PT_ID) 
        INNER JOIN tblWellDescription 
            ON tblTransducer.Hole_ID = tblWellDescription.Hole_ID
WHERE   (((qryAutonumber2.WL_Elev_Difference)>[tblFlag]![upper]) 
AND     ((qryAutonumber2.Date_Difference)<=1) 
AND     ((tblWellDescription.Well_Type)="mw" 
    Or (tblWellDescription.Well_Type)="pz" 
    Or (tblWellDescription.Well_Type)="vd"))
ORDER BY qryAutonumber2.PT_ID_1;
```

I'm not concerned with better ways to write the statement and do not want to run VBA.  I simply want this statement to not disappear so it seems like some sort of a corruption issue.  Further, I ran an old saved copy with the same back end linked tables and it works fine.

I appreciate any responses.

Best,

Matt

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was last answered in 2014, Microsoft has documented a bug that sometimes causes queries to disappear: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3189523/query-must-have-at-least-one-destination-field-error-when-you-run-an-a

Briefly, if a query is used at the source of data for the DoCmd.OutputTo method, and if the query has been edited only in SQL View, not in Design View, then the structure of the query is disrupted when the OutputTo method is executed. Microsoft recommends two workarounds:

1. Turn off Track name AutoCorrect info; this would have the disadvantage of losing the auto-corrections that are ordinarily performed when object names are changed.
2. Make sure that each query is saved from Design View, not from SQL View; this is sometimes impossible for complex queries.

Instead, there is a simple workaround: instead of outputting the query, select the query result into a temporary table and output that. It is possible that this will lose some Order By information, since tables are unordered; I haven't done the testing to know for sure.

Allan Browne has documented other problems with using Track name AutoCorrect, as of April 2010: http://allenbrowne.com/bug-03.html . I'm starting to suspect this might be related to some other inexplicable crashes I've seen lately.

Answer (score 0):

Access mangles any moderately complex query. The problem is when you open the query in the editor, Access tries to 'understand' it to show it in the query designer view. In the process, it rewrites parts of the query into a form it understands better. So you will see it do things like take a simple condition:

```
where x = 1
```

and surround it with parentheses and prefix all column names with table names:

```
where ((tblLongTableName.x) = 1)
```

Sometimes it doesn't understand the query at all and ends up erasing it in the process. This is probably what is happening to you. Nowadays I go to pretty great lengths to keep moderately complex queries outside the query editor. I store them instead in a hidden table inside the database file, inside a memo column. When I need to edit the query, I copy it from the table into a good text editor, and make my edits there. When I need to run the query on a day-to-day basis, I make sure that whatever form or report is running the query first deletes and recreates the query (using VBA) just before running it, so on that first it's guaranteed to be untouched.

You can do something similar with your query. Below I've simplified it to the essentials.

```
drop view qryMyQuery;
create view qryMyQuery as
select
  q.Date_1 as Date_Time
, q.DTW
, q.Temp_C
, q.WL_Elev_Difference as Daily_WL_Elev_Difference
, q.PT_ID_1 as PT_ID
, q.Remarks
from
  tblFlag as f
, (
    qryAutonumber2 as q
    inner join tblTransducer as t
    on q.PT_ID_1 = t.PT_ID
  ) inner join tblWellDescription as w
  on t.Hole_ID = w.Hole_ID
where q.WL_Elev_Difference > f.[upper]
and q.Date_Difference <= 1
and w.Well_Type in ('mw', 'pz', 'vd')
order by q.PT_ID_1;
```

To store queries in a table, you need three things:

1. A table `tblSqlScripts` with the following columns:

   - Name: varchar(255)
   - Contents: memo
2. A VBA sub that can execute an arbitrary number of SQL commands passed in as a string:

   ```
   Public Sub ExecSqlStr(strSql As String)
     strSql = Replace(Replace(strSql, Chr(10), " "), Chr(13), " ")
     vSql = Split(strSql, "; ")

     On Error GoTo MessageError
     CurrentProject.Connection.BeginTrans
     For Each s In vSql
       s = Trim(s)
       If Left(s, 2) <> "--" Then
         CurrentProject.Connection.Execute s
       End If
     Next
     CurrentProject.Connection.CommitTrans

     Exit Sub
   MessageError:
     Debug.Print "ERROR: " & Err.Description
     Debug.Print
     CurrentProject.Connection.RollbackTrans
   End Sub
   ```

   Note that the above procedure will execute everything inside a SQL transaction, so if one SQL statement fails, none of them will have any effect. All must succeed for the changes to take place.
3. A VBA sub that takes the name of a SQL script, looks it up in `tblSqlScripts`, and executes it using (2):

   ```
   Public Sub ExecStoredSql(strName as String)
     strSql = DLookup("Contents", "tblSqlScripts", "[Name] = " & strName)
     ExecSqlStr strSql
   End Sub
   ```

Now, you can store any arbitrary SQL in the `tblSqlScripts` table and execute it in VBA with a one-liner. E.g., if you store the above `drop view ...; create view ...` query script in the table (with name `qryMyQuery`), you can execute it to re-create the query in a pristine form with the following VBA:

```
ExecStoredSql "qryMyQuery"
```

Comment: Yawar, thank you.  You added validity to my thought process regarding Access queries and SQL handling with my skill level.  I, like you, save all SQL statements in a text editor but had not considered saving a separate table with the statements in a memo field.  I resolved my problem by re-importing the query from an older version rather than pasting SQL into the existing query.  Not sure if that was the fix but something in that process made it work... for now.  This problem will resurface in the future I am sure.

Comment: @user3642649 - sure, if it works I'm all for it. I just wouldn't trust it very far :-) Anyway, about storing in separate text files yes, I did the same for a while but then I thought that accdb files can store indefinite amounts of text in memo fields....

Comment: When you use vba to run your SQL query, is the table's memo field called in the code?

Comment: @user3642649 - I've expanded my answer with the details.

Comment: I feel this should be filed under "Reasons to migrate off of MS Access".

Comment: @BaconBits - hey, nothing's perfect.

Comment: Okay, conceptually simple.  Lookup the string in the table field and run it.  Turns out I will have to use this "workaround" or similar because Access is only keeping my SQL statement some of the time now.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user3642649 - we aim to please :-)